# How can I use the do shell script in applescript?

Tags: xcode, shell, applescript

I'm brand new to Applescript and also have some limited experience with Terminal. I made simple shell script today that I saved on my desktop. It's named "Test.sh" and just copies a file from one folder to another. When I run `sh ~/Desktop/Test.sh`from within Terminal, everything runs just fine. However, when I type `do shell script "/Volumes/volume_name/Users/username/Desktop/Test.sh"` inside Xcode  as an Applescript command, nothing happens. I am using Xcode 4.4.1 on Mac OS 10.7.4 (though I guess it's irrelevant). What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you shell script is executable (`chmod +x Test.sh`) ?

Comment: I used this command but it returned `chmod: Test.sh: No such file or directory`. I changed `Test.sh` to `~/Desktop/Test.sh`, but now it only waits for another command, without doing anything. What am I supposed to see as a result?

Comment: OK - that just makes the script executable - now you should try running your AppleScript code again and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Because the path of the startup disk doesn't begin with "**/Volumes/**"

Use this to get the correct path

```
set shScript to quoted form of POSIX path of ((path to desktop folder as string) & "Test.sh")
do shell script shScript
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not seem to be working. What ways are there to create a .sh file. Maybe mine just isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Enter Terminal and type the following:

```
cd ~
cd Desktop
sh Test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider that the applescript you want to run inside the shell script is to empty the trash. Follow these steps:

1. Open Terminal
2. type "touch sample.sh" and press return
3. Type "chmod +x sample.sh" and press return
4. Type "open -e sample.sh" and press return, this open text editor
5. Paste the below code in text file and save it.

## !/bin/bash

osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"
empty trash
end tell'

1. Go back to terminal. Type "./sample.sh". this will result in empty trash.